# How to get ErrorStream for large Big Runtime.Exec operations

Tags: java

I'm using the following code to get ErrorStream.

```
shellinput[0] = "/system/xbin/dd if=/dev/zero of=";
shellinput[1] = newvfspath;
shellinput[2] = "/gtj.img bs=1000000 count=";
shellinput[3] = gtjsize;
System.out
        .println("Error Code (making new "
                + newvfspath
                + "/gtj.img ) :
            + errorstreamReader(shellinput)"
private String errorstreamReader(String[] shellinput) {
    InputStream inputstream = null;
    String esrval = null;
    System.out.println("Entering errorstreamReader");
    //hack to prevent executing null
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        if (shellinput[i] == null) {
            shellinput[i] = "";
        }
    }
    try {
    System.out.println("Executing " + shellinput[0]
                + shellinput[1] + shellinput[2] + shellinput[3]);
        inputstream = Runtime
                .getRuntime()
                .exec(shellinput[0] + " " + shellinput[1] + " "
                        + shellinput[2]).getErrorStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = null;
    try {
        inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        esrval = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader).readLine();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return esrval;
}
```

But the problem with this is `/system/xbin/dd if=/dev/zero of=./mnt/sdcard/cimages_2/gtj.img bs=1000000 count=100` is a pretty large operation, it takes like 8 secs. So It's not executing. How do I fix this?

**Edit :**

Problem was not that it is a big operation. I figures it out. Thanks.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Irrespective of the time the process takes, you should be able to read from the input stream as and when data is available? So what is not executing? Can you give me more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This fixed it:**

```
shellinput[0] = "/system/xbin/dd if=/dev/zero of=";
shellinput[1] = newvfspath;
shellinput[2] = "/gtj.img bs=1000000 count=";
shellinput[3] = gtjsize;
System.out
        .println("Error Code (making new "
                + newvfspath
                + "/gtj.img ) :
            + errorstreamReader(shellinput)"
private String errorstreamReader(String[] shellinput) {
    InputStream inputstream = null;
    String esrval = null;
    System.out.println("Entering errorstreamReader");
    //hack to prevent executing null
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        if (shellinput[i] == null) {
            shellinput[i] = "";
        }
    }
    try {
    System.out.println("Executing " + shellinput[0]
                + shellinput[1] + shellinput[2] + shellinput[3]);
        inputstream = Runtime
                .getRuntime()
                .exec(shellinput[0]
                + shellinput[1] + shellinput[2] + shellinput[3]).getErrorStream();// this fixed it, typo
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = null;
    try {
        inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        esrval = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader).readLine();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return esrval;
}
```